# Walker_Nav_Menu() for top level links only

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

I have a menu in the WordPress backend that looks like this:

```html
What we do
  Solutions
    Solution 1
    Solution 2
  Services
    Service 1
Contact
```

Items `What we do` and `Contact` are top level links and I only want these level 1 links to show in my main `header`.

As such, I created a custom `walker` to achieve this:

```html
<?php

class simple_header extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

  /*
  * start_lvl : Responsible for start of a new level, such as <ul>
  * end_lvl : Responsible for end of a level, such as </ul>
  * start_el : Responsible for start of inner element, such as <li>
  * end_el : Responsible for end of inner element, such as <\li>
  */

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
      $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    }

    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
      $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';


        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = $item->ID;

        $class_names = 'header__nav-menu-li';

        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
          $class_names .= ' header__nav-menu-li--active';
        }

        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        if ($depth === 0) {
          $output .= $indent . '<li data-test' . $class_names .'>';
        }

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        // New
        if ($depth === 0) {
          $atts['class'] = 'header__nav-menu-anchor link-header';
        }

        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes)) {
          $atts['class'] .= ' link-header--active';
        }

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
          if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
          }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;

        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
      if ($depth === 0) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
      }
    }
}

?>
```

However, with the above `walker`, it still prints out the child markup. The HTML looks like this:

```html
<li class="header__nav-menu-li header__nav-menu-li--active">
  <a href="#" class="header__nav-menu-anchor link-header link-header--active">What we do</a>
  <a href="#">Solutions</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
</li>
```

I have defined `$depth === 0` in my walker, so unsure why it's printing child links?

Comment: You are still adding those links, `$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';` ff. - you did not make _that_ part dependent on the current depth level at all.

Comment: @CBroe - The issue still remains after doing the following: `if ($depth === 0) { $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>'; }`. Whilst it stops the child links from being wrapped in `<a>` tags, it still prints them as `text nodes`.

Comment: Just to be clear, whatever you are wanting to do can't be done by just passing a depth of `0` to the `wp_nav_menu` function? A quick glance shows that all of the CSS classes you are using appear to be an alias of the native ones, so this feels like it can be done in CSS alone.

Comment: _"Whilst it stops the child links from being wrapped in <a> tags, it still prints them as text nodes"_ - that's because creation of the link text content, happens on the _next_ line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, at the `start_lvl` and `end_lvl` you would output `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags respectively to start and end a new  **list**.

Every item in your menu consists of an **anchor** tag wrapped inside a **list item**:

`<li><a href="target-url">Target</a></li>`

In your code you only have an 'if' statement around the code that adds the **list item** tags to the output.

On the last line of your `start_el` function you still add the **anchor**.

Instead of wrapping an if statement around the parts where you want to output markup, my advice would be to add the following line of code as the first line of your `start_el` function:

`if($depth !== 0) { return; }`

That way you skip execution of code for items that are not in the first level.